# How to run graph algorithms on distributed graph database using Titan+Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, titan

I have a distributed graph using **Titan+Cassandra(titan-server-0.4.4)** deployed over 4 machines. The graph is about call detail records.

I have 2 types of nodes-user node and call nodes. User nodes contain only one property "user id". Call nodes contain 2 properties-timestamp of the call(date and time), and duration of the call. For each call, there are two edges from the call nodes to the respective pair of users involved in the call. The edges contains the latitude and longitude for the corresponding user as properties. All properties are indexed.

I have two questions now:

1. Given a specific user id,say "A", how do I find the users which "A" called within a specific period of time ?
2. For running graph algorithms like community detection, what tools should I be looking into ? I came across a suggestion of using Furnace, but couldn't find any documentation for Furnace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider adjusting your schema to denormalize the "call" vertex by placing the date/time on the edge.  In that way you can take advantage of vertex centric indices and see a faster query times.

http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/wikidoc/0.4.4/Vertex-Centric-Indices.html

To get the answer to your first query (I will assume you denormalized and that the date/time is stored as a long on the edge), you could then do:

```
g.V('user','A').as('callerA').outE.interval('time',startTime,endTime)
    .inV.out.except('callerA')
```

As for algorithms, TinkerPop doesn't support such things in TinkerPop2 - Furnace has never had an official release.  We expect such things in TinkerPop3 which is coming closer to GA - http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/3.0.0.M7/

For now, you would have to write your own.  There is a clustering algorithm in Furnace which you should be able to adapt to your work - you can find it [here](https://github.com/tinkerpop/furnace/blob/60713be1e497476ed238b39372e334184ecf575e/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/furnace/algorithms/vertexcentric/programs/clustering/PeerPressureProgram.java).  If you take a look at the tests you can see how it works.

Comment: I was compelled to use the "call" vertex, since each entry in my data file(from which I generated the graph), contains only one end of a call, and the entries are not sorted with respect to time. The data file contains over 9E8 entries. Anyway, I think your query works with gremlin. Will it work with java blueprint api ? If not, can you give me the equivalent bluprint query?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you get rid of the "call" vertex.  I just meant for you to store "time" in both the "call" vertex and the edge.  I don't recommend trying to write this with the Blueprints API - that's the point of Gremlin. It simplifies queries that could be many dozens/hundreds of lines long into one concise statement that is easy to read and easy to maintain.  While it is possible to write this traversal at the Blueprints  level (i.e. Gremlin uses Blueprints so anything you can do with Gremlin can be done with Blueprints) it would be very counterproductive to do so.

Comment: Got it, will be using gremlin then from now on.